# Bootstrap col-sm-6 Image resize div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When using col-sm-6 I can not align the picture and the box-text. I am not sure if it is a problem of image or margin/padding etc.

[image: pic]

html:

```js
/* css: */

.category {
 padding-top: 3rem;
 padding-bottom: 3rem;
 background-color: #096;
}
.categoryimg {
 display: block;
 height: 487px;
 max-width: 100%;
}
.categorytext {
 padding-top: 12%;
 font-family: Avenir;
 color: #0670EB;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: white;
 width: 50%;
 height: 487px;
 float: right;
}
.categorytext1 {
 padding-top: 12%;
 font-family: Avenir;
 color: #0670EB;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: white;
 width: 50%;
 height: 487px;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 categorytext1">
        <h2>LANGUAGE</h2>
        <p class="lead">Nibook is a platform where foreigners can change their frame time into money by crafting beautiful services and share them with the locals within in-person or online experiences.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6"> <img src="img/language.png" class="categoryimg" alt="Generic placeholder image"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Next picture is what I try to achieve. I try to put 1 img and 1 text box by row and make it as a table with padding between each boxed. I am not sure how to resolve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 pad0">
     <img src="http://ingridwu.dmmdmcfatter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/placeholder.png" class="categoryimg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 pad0">
     <div class="categorytext1">
      <h2>LANGUAGE</h2>
      <p class="lead">Nibook is a platform where foreigners can change their frame time into money by crafting beautiful services and share them with the locals within in-person or online experiences.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 pad0">
     <img src="http://ingridwu.dmmdmcfatter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/placeholder.png" class="categoryimg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 pad0">
     <div class="categorytext1">
      <h2>LANGUAGE</h2>
      <p class="lead">Nibook is a platform where foreigners can change their frame time into money by crafting beautiful services and share them with the locals within in-person or online experiences.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<style>
body{
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.pad0{
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.category {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  background-color: #096;
}

.categoryimg {
    display:block;
    height:487px;
    max-width:100%;

}

.categorytext1 {
padding: 0 15px;
padding-top:12%;
font-family: Avenir;
color:#0670EB;
font-weight:bold;
background-color:white;
height:487px;
float:left;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.categorytext1` is changing the width of the div, that is most likely messing with the bootstrap style for `col-sm-6`

```
.categorytext1 {
    padding-top:12%;
    font-family: Avenir;
    color:#0670EB;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:white;
    *****width:50%;*****
    height:487px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I delete width in both .categorytext and .categorytext1 and nothing change

Comment: Is there any styling on the `container` class?